# Google Maps Styled (API) - use javascript

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to apply a code from this wizard http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

for example:

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      { "hue": "#00ccff" },
      { "visibility": "simplified" }
    ]
  }
]
```

in [this](http://jsbin.com/amodur/7/edit) code

Anyone willing to help? I sincerely don't know hot to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

pass the example-array in your question to the `styles`-option of the map :

```
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.70727541512677,
                                         20.578157256250062),
          zoom: 7, 
          styles:[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      { "hue": "#00ccff" },
      { "visibility": "simplified" }
    ]
  }
],
          panControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
```

```
},


      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
```

});

http://jsbin.com/owaxas/1/edit